# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf - What's the difference between th:value and th:field when you iterate multiple items?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to display multiple items from database to Thymeleaf view, using HTML Form so that I can make a change and update to the database.

I was going to use **th:field** . but it occurred error. when I tried to use **th:value**. and It shows data.

```
<div th:each="item : ${courses}">
  <form th:object="${item}">
    <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" id="name" name="name" /> // error occur
  </form>
</div>
```

error following.

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'item' available as request attribute
```

Whereas this below code works fine.

```
<div th:each="item : ${courses}">
  <form th:object="${item}">
    <input th:value="*{name}" type="text" id="name" name="name" /> // ok
  </form>
</div>
```

Am I on the right track? Can you explain why? and the difference between field and value?

Comment: I'm not sure `th:field` even exists, since I couldn't find it on the docs. `th:value`, however, puts the result of the provided expression into the input's `value` attribute.

Comment: It talks about `th:field` in the `integrating with spring` documention -- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom line is that you can only use `th:object` and `th:field` together on a base model attribute.  That means you can't use it when iterating (because `${item}` doesn't exist on the model, it's a variable generated by the `th:each`).  The requirements are spelled out [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form):

> Values for `th:object` attributes in form tags must be variable expressions (`${...}`) specifying only the name of a model attribute, without property navigation. This means that an expression like `${seedStarter}` is valid, but `${seedStarter.data}` would not be.
>
> Once inside the `<form>` tag, no other `th:object` attribute can be specified. This is consistent with the fact that HTML forms cannot be nested.

`th:field` sets the `name`, `id`, and `value` of a field. So they are somewhat interchangeable but you should use `th:field` whenever possible  because it offers the extra integration with spring, and works on all kinds of input -- but these are really only useful when you are editing a single object on a page.

Since you have multiple objects you are iterating, you're going to have to manually set the `name`, `id`, and `value` like you are doing.

Comment: can you please check this issue ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398872/spring-boot-and-thymeleaf-to-edit-multiple-many-to-many-relationship